# Change Safari Technology Preview's interface language

Tags: macos

The interface language of Safari Technology Preview is always English even if I use other primary languages for the OS. Can I change it to my system default language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Safari TP does not come with any translations for the user interface.

```
/Applications/Safari Technology Preview.app/Contents/Resources/*.lproj
Base.lproj en.lproj
```

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/*.lproj
ar.lproj Base.lproj ca.lproj cs.lproj da.lproj de.lproj el.lproj en.lproj en_AU.lproj en_GB.lproj es.lproj es_419.lproj fi.lproj fr.lproj fr_CA.lproj he.lproj hi.lproj hr.lproj hu.lproj id.lproj it.lproj ja.lproj ko.lproj ms.lproj nl.lproj no.lproj pl.lproj pt.lproj pt_PT.lproj ro.lproj ru.lproj sk.lproj sv.lproj th.lproj tr.lproj uk.lproj vi.lproj zh_CN.lproj zh_HK.lproj zh_TW.lproj
```

It may be possible to copy translations from Safari to Safari TP, but I have not tested this.